# Не корректные байты в xml

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

При загрузке xml страницы в браузере выдает ошибку
error on line 62164 at column 28: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0x0F 0xE2 0x80 0x93

пробую чистить эти байты через preg_replace в цикле

$invalid_characters = '/[0\x0F-0\xE2-0\x80-0\x93]/';

```
$arr[] = [
        'title' => preg_replace($invalid_characters, '', $c['h1']),
        'date' => date('D, d M Y h:i:s O', $c['publishDate']),
        'url' => $c['cUrl'],
        'body' => preg_replace($invalid_characters, '', $c['cBody']),
        'related' => getRandomFive($rubs[$rubid], $c['_id'])
      ];
```

но в title и body возвращаются пустые значения
у меня ошибка в $invalid_characters ?
Помогите плиз

Comment: Удалите `0` перед всеми ``\x``

Comment: удалил, все равно пустую строчку возвращает

Answer (score 1):

помог паттерн '/\x0F\xE2\x80\x93/'

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

```
 $xml = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $xml);
```

Comment: увы, не помогло ((